# Replace specific part of the domain leaving the rest untouched

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite a specific part of the URL while keeping the rest of it, more precisely the extension.

```
my.domain.co/posts/something
```

to

```
my.domain.ai/posts/something
```

I tried many suggestions but always hitting a dead end. The one thing I managed to cook reading the redirect guides is this but it's not working. I basically want to replace `.co` with `.ai`.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]*\.)?my.mydomain.co$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%my.mydomain.ai/$1 [R=301,L]
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]*\.)?my.mydomain.co$
> RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%my.mydomain.ai/$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

This is more complex than it needs to be, given the example you posted. Your example does not include any additional sub-subdomains, so why are you allowing for this in the regex? You also have an erroneous `%` in the *susbtitution* string.

Something like the following is all that's required:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(my\.domain)\.co [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%1.ai/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This rule nears to go near the top of your `.htaccess` file.

The `%1` backreference contains `my.domain`, captured from the preceding *CondPattern* - this is simply to save repetition.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing, since any erroneous 301 (permanent) redirects will have been cached by the browser.

Test first with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues.

Comment: Added right after RewriteEngine On in the .htaccess file but It returns Internal Server Error. From what I understand, the ^creates some kind of variable from (my\.domain\) and then it replaces that with %1 attaching .ai and the rest of the url with $1
The logic is there, but it returns Internal Server Error

Comment: @GorastCvetkovski Ah, sorry, there was a typo in the regex! (I've corrected it in my answer). It should be `^(my\.domain)\.co`, not `^(my\.domain\).co` - notice the placement of the last slash, before the dot, not before the closing bracket.